# MATLAB: X-axis plotting out of range

Tags: matlab

I have `x` stops at `0.5*1.0e-04` but the plot plots through it to `0.6*1.0e-04`. How to deal with this out of range error? I try to plot `real(y)` instead but it does not help.

```
x = 1.0e-04 *[0 0.050 0.1000 0.1500 0.2000 0.2500 0.3000 0.3500 0.4000 0.4500 0.5000];
y = [2.0000 + 0.0000i   1.6096 + 0.0000i   1.5986 + 0.0000i   1.5903 - 0.0000i...
    1.5842 - 0.0000i   1.3794 - 0.0000i   1.5775 - 0.0000i   1.5790 - 0.0000i...
    1.5827 - 0.0000i   1.6867 - 0.0000i   1.5882 - 0.0000i];
figure(1)
plot(x, y,'-b','LineWidth',2); %plot(x, real(y),'-b','LineWidth',2);
```

[image]

Comment: Try xlim([0 0.5e-4])

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with Matlab formatting your output. Try this command after you are done plotting:

```
axis tight;
```

Alternatively, you can manually [set the axis limits](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) as such:

```
xlim = [0,0.5*1.0e-04]
```